# Методы уже определены в *.obj

Tags: c++, методы, компоновщик

Добрый день, первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой. При компиляции вылазит следующее **для каждого метода**:

```
Ошибка  LNK2005 "public: __thiscall GVS::GVS(void)" (??0GVS@@QAE@XZ) уже определен в head.obj   kurs    D:\cpp\kurs\kurs\main.obj   1
```

Собственно сам код:
**head.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class s4et4ik                       //шаблон
{
private:
    double V;                       //расход в секунду
    double energy;                  //потребляемая энергия
    double V_1;                     //расход за сутки
public:
    int T1_enter;
    int T2_exit;
    s4et4ik();                      //конструктор по умолчанию
    s4et4ik(double v_per_sec, double Energy, double v_per_day) { // конструктор для счетчиков
        V = v_per_sec;
        V_1 = v_per_day;
        energy = Energy;
    }

    double get_V();                 //получение значения мгновенного расхода
    double get_energy();            //получение потребляемой энергии
    double get_V_1();               //получение расхода за сутки
    int get_t1();                   //получение температуры на входе
    int get_t2();                   //получение температуры на выходе
    void change_V_per_sec();        //изменение значения расхода в секунду
    void change_V_per_day();        //изменение значение расхода за сутки
    void t1_enter();                //температура на входе
    void t2_exit();                 //температура на выходе
    virtual void save();            //сохранение полученных значений
    virtual void show_info()=0;     //отображение данных

    virtual ~s4et4ik() {}
};
class GVS : public s4et4ik {        //счетчик горячей воды
private:
    double Q;                       //Гигокаллории
public:
    GVS();                          //конструктор по умолчанию
    GVS(double v_per_sec, double v_per_day, double energy) : s4et4ik(v_per_sec, energy, v_per_day) { // конструктор для ГВС

    }

    void show_info();               //отображение данных
    double ggcall();                //расчет гигокаллорий
    void save();
    ~GVS();


};

class HV : public s4et4ik {
public:
    HV();                           //конструктор по умолчанию
    HV(double v_per_sec, double v_per_day, double energy) : s4et4ik(v_per_sec, energy, v_per_day) {}//конструктор для ХВ
    void show_info();
    void save();
    ~HV();

};
```

**head.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "head.h"

void GVS::show_info() {
    cout << "\t\t\tСчетчик горячей воды" << endl << endl
        << "Мгновенный расход: " << this->get_V() << endl
        << "Расход за сутки: " << this->get_V_1() << endl
        << "Потребляемая энергия: " << this->get_energy()
        << "Гигокаллории: " << this->ggcall() << endl;
}

double s4et4ik::get_energy() {
    return this->energy;
}

double s4et4ik::get_V() {
    return this->V;
}
double s4et4ik::get_V_1() {
    return this->V_1;
}

double GVS::ggcall() {
    this->Q = get_V() / (get_t2() - get_t1());
    return this->Q;
}

int s4et4ik::get_t2() {
    return T2_exit;
}

int s4et4ik::get_t1() {
    return T1_enter;
}

void HV::show_info() {
    cout << "Температура воды: " << this->get_t1() << endl
        << "Мгновенный расход: " << this->get_V() << endl
        << "Расход за сутки: " << this->get_V_1() << endl;
}

void s4et4ik::change_V_per_day() {}

void s4et4ik::change_V_per_sec() {}

void s4et4ik::t1_enter() {}

void s4et4ik::t2_exit() {}

void s4et4ik::save() {}

void GVS::save() {}

void HV::save() {}

s4et4ik::s4et4ik() {}

GVS::GVS() {}
GVS::~GVS() {}

HV::HV() {}
HV::~HV() {}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "head.cpp"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не делайте так:

```
#include "head.cpp"
```

Включайте через `#include` заголовочный файл с *объявлениями*, но не с *определениями*. Так, как сделали вы, у вас масса *определенных* (не объявленных, а именно определенных) функций оказывается скомпилированной как в файле `head.obj`, так и в `main.obj`, и компоновщик не знает, какой из вариантов выбрать.

Comment: Спасибо,  помогло