# class Store store уже определен в main.obj

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь с запуском простого проекта. Суть такая: есть файл `main.cpp`, туда добавляю модуль State, внутри которого должен храниться инстанс класса `Store`. Но при запуске выдает ошибку:

> class Store store уже определен в main.obj"

Структура кода такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл `main.cpp`:

```
#include "State.cpp"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("123");
    return 0;
}
```

файл `State.cpp`:

```
#include "Store.h"

Store store;
```

файл `Store.cpp`:

```
#include "Store.h"
```

файл `Store.h`:

```
#pragma once
class Store
{
};
```

Нашел подобный вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741767/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-obj), но у меня возникло еще больше вопросов. Как я понял нужно подключать только заголовочные файлы, а не cpp расширения. Тогда и для `State` нужно завести расширение `.h`, правильно? Я так понимаю если файлы `Store.h` это заголовки класса, то нужно саму логику писать в Store.cpp и класс продублировать? Т.е. допустим у меня в классе есть методы, то в cpp я пишу реализацию, а в h только имя метода(сигнатуру) или как? Но тогда у меня в консоль падает ошибка: "переопределение типа class". Можете помочь что куда нужно писать и где что должно находиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то, так:

**Store.h**

```
...
extern Store store;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "State.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

Обычно (подчеркиваю — *обычно*, но не без исключений)

- объявление класса — в заголовочном файле
- реализация класса — в .cpp-файле
- объекты класса — там, где используются. Если есть какие-то ну *очень важные* причины в наличии глобального объекта, как у вас — его объявление как `extern` в заголовочном файле, определение — в одном из .cpp. Есть также вариант с `inline`-объявлением.